# Implementing workflow in bestpractical.com RT

Tags: rt

I would like to implement simple workflow system inside the Bestpractical RT.
My approach is:

- Participant (RT user) creates or is given Workitem (Ticket) inside the Business Process (Queue)
- OnResolve scrip checks change Ticket status to Open and change TicketOwner to next Participant.
- OnReject scrip changes Ticket status to Open and gives it back to previous Participant.

My questions are:
- Is there good scrip examples to manipulate statuses?
- How can I debug scrips?
- How to disable built-in scrips for queues?

I read that it is possible to create a module for RT with actions which can then be called from scrips, but cannot find good documentation/examples. Please advise if you have one.

And the last question, how to enable developer mode in RT?

Thank you very much in advance,

Alexei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you're running an RT version 4.0.x.

For the workflow you described, you probably want to create new tickets for each phase rather than having tickets set to resolved, then re-opening them. You can create new tickets in scrips to do this. You can also create link relationships between them like Depends On or Parent Child.

You can find user-contributed samples of various conditions on the [RT wiki](http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/CustomConditionSnippets). You'll see a bunch of debug output for scrips if you turn on debug mode in your logging config. You can also put warn statements in code to see additional output in the RT logs. To disable scrips, edit the scrip and set the Stage to disabled. These built-in scrips are global, so if you want to set them per-queue, you can create scrips under the queue configuration to make them queue-specific.

The best examples of actions and conditions are the RT code itself. You can find documentation at the bottom of the [main documentation page](http://bestpractical.com/rt/docs/latest/). From there, you can look in the lib directory in the RT code to see how the actions and conditions are implemented. It's generally easier to get started creating actions and conditions by selecting User defined and using the text boxes on the scrip edit page.

You can set devel mode in the [configuration file](http://bestpractical.com/rt/docs/latest/RT_Config.html#Development-options). Make use you set these in RT_SiteConfig.pm, not Config.pm. You'll also want to set [you log levels to debug](http://bestpractical.com/rt/docs/latest/RT_Config.html#Logging).